# Numpy Correlation Error for Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, correlation

I am trying to show correlation between two individual lists. Before installing Numpy, I parsed World Bank data for GDP values and the number of internet users and stored them in two separate lists. Here is the snippet of code. This is just for gdp07. I actually have more lists for more years and other data such as unemployment.

```
import numpy as np

file = open('final_gdpnum.txt', 'r')
gdp07 = []
for line in file:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    gdp07.append(fields [0])    

file2 = open('internetnum.txt', 'r')
netnum07 = []
for line in file2:
    fields2 = line.strip().split()
    nnetnum07.append(fields2 [0])

print np.correlate(gdp07,netnum07,"full")
```

The error I get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Project3,py", line 83, in ,module.
    print np.correlate(gdp07, netnum07, "full")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 645, in correlate
    return multiarray.correlate2(a,v,mode))
ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize
```

Just for the record, I am using Cygwin with Python 2.6 on a Windows computer. I am only using Numpy along with its dependencies and other parts of its build (gcc compiler). Any help would be great. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps that is the error when you try to input data as string, since according to python docs strip() return a string

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Try parsing the data to whatever type you want

As you can see here

```
In [14]:np.correlate(["3", "2","1"], [0, 1, 0.5])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/dog/<ipython-input-14-a0b588b9af44> in <module>()
----> 1 np.correlate(["3", "2","1"], [0, 1, 0.5])

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in correlate(a, v, mode, old_behavior)
    643         return multiarray.correlate(a,v,mode)
    644     else:
--> 645         return multiarray.correlate2(a,v,mode)
    646 
    647 def convolve(a,v,mode='full'):

ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize
```

try parsing the values

```
In [15]: np.correlate([int("3"), int("2"),int("1")], [0, 1, 0.5])
Out[15]: array([ 2.5])



import numpy as np

file = open('final_gdpnum.txt', 'r')
gdp07 = []
for line in file:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    gdp07.append(int(fields [0]))    

file2 = open('internetnum.txt', 'r')
netnum07 = []
for line in file2:
    fields2 = line.strip().split()
    nnetnum07.append(int(fields2 [0]))

print np.correlate(gdp07,netnum07,"full")
```

your other error is a character ending problem
i hope this works, since I dont think I can reproduce it since I have a linux box that supports utf-8 by default.
I went by ipython help(codecs) documentation
http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/dict-files.html

```
import codecs

f =  codecs.open(file, "r", codecs.BOM_UTF8)
for line in f:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    gdp07.append(int(fields [0]))
```

Comment: I think you're right about the string output. I tried your suggestion first. But it's giving me a different value error, saying that it is an invalid literal.
"ValueError: Invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xef\xbb\xbf553,771' 

I tried taking out strip() and only leaving split(), but my original problem of "data type must provide an itemsize" remains.

Comment: I guess you can try a float or give us a small snippet of the data

Comment: Haha yeah I tried with float as well. It was the same problem with int... :(

Data the way it's presented right now

['11.1', '5.9', '3', '22.7', '13.7', '3.6', '3.7'] 
Of course there are more lists and they're much larger

Comment: I not really experience with python, but this \xef\xbb\xbf is the encoding for utf-8 
import codecs
with codecs.open(file, "r", "utf-8-sig") as f:
     f.readline()
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359832/dealing-with-utf-8-numbers-in-python

Comment: I ended up just changing all my files from unicode to ANSI. They're all just numbers anyways so I don't think I will any problems with that. I am still have troubling converting my lists into float however. That is really frustrating....

Comment: Is this really how your data is presented in the file? ['11.1', '5.9', '3', '22.7', '13.7', '3.6', '3.7']
If it is comma seperated, then your have to use .split(',')
if there are those strange brackets, then you will have to remove them

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast data to float type. it works for me!